# Where to store framework code for challenges?

Tags: discussion

Some challenges are provided with some kind of framework in which the submissions should be ran in, e.g. [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenges. I wrote the [*catch the cat*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51029/asymmetrical-koth-catch-the-cat-cat-thread?answertab=active#tab-top) challenge, which needs several files for the controller. These are currently stored as a gist.

Recently I wanted to delete my github account but noticed that the whole controller code is still on this challenge. As far as I understand the philisophy of Stack Exchange is that Questions and Answers should not rely on external sources but should rather be fully self contained, such that those Q/A's are still available when the corresponding users aren't active anymore. That leads me to the thinking that outside sources that are personally managed (that can be deleted any time) are *not* appropriate.

This leads to my question: **How should this kind of *framework code* be stored in order to be preserved for the future?**

- Is there some kind of file upload for files other than images available?
- Should the whole source code be pasted into the question? (possibly cluttering the whole question with code nobody wants to read / or abusing JS+HTML snippets for hiding the code?)
- Are external sources like Pastebin/file sharing sites/Github/ acceptable?

Answer (score 8):

This one requires a little more setup and some time dedication by someone, but it could easily be managed by the mods -- it'd be at the very most a few minutes a day, probably less, given the relative lack of KOTH questions.

### Send it to a community GitHub repo (managed by a group)

Depending on where you have the files, you could either [transfer ownership](https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-a-repository/) or make a pull request adding the files. It would only be the final, bugtested version; this isn't a development repo, just a warehouse for code you don't want to maintain anymore.

I'd recommend that, if this happens, we put a notice on [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) saying that controller code can and should be uploaded to the repo when it's completely finished. That way, anyone can look at the code and try it out, or at least see how it works to verify that there aren't any bugs.

The group would consist of either just mods, a certain selection of mods and high-rep users, or something else. It would be charged with making sure no spam edits or files get into the repo.

Comment: Where can we find those community accounts? Does this work for gists too? If no, how can git-illiterate still participate?

Comment: @flawr I was suggesting that mods make and maintain a repo. I just worded it badly. Git-illiterate people can participate by uploading their files via the Github web interface, which is so intuitive that I as a git-illiterate ten-year-old could figure out how to upload files to it.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I know an almost computer-illiterate 8-year-old who has used that interface. However, after deleting a few repos, I didn't let them use it again. (Hurray for backups!)

Answer (score 2):

## (experimental suggestion) as Zip file base64 encoded in a snippet

I know this is not ideal either, but I just worked out that you can base64-encode a zip file, and use a link tag to store the encoded string and provide a download via JS-HTML snippet:

1. Show snippet
2. Run code snippet
3. Click the link
4. If this does not work, try right click -> save as

```html
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64,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" download="src.zip">
download controller (if it does not work, try right click, save as,...)</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Provide the compressed code

1. Compress your code (LZMA, bzip2, or something else)
2. Post the compressed output (encoded in hexadecimal or base64)
3. Optionally, provide a program in a common language (such as Java or Python) that acts as a wrapper for the decompression.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I suggested, except that my suggestion does directly use the browser for interpreting the base64 string as a file, right?

Comment: @flawr I was attempting to generalize more

Comment: Ah I see. I think it would be better (still not ideal) to provide it directly via snippet. We could also make a meta post with a snippet that takes a filea s input and outputs directly the code you can include in your challenge.